# C++: Creating a makefile with two executables? C++

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, executable

I have two C++ programs that both share a class. progOne.cpp and progTwo.cpp. They both share a class, fileInfo.cpp with the appropriate fileInfo.h file.

This is how I tried to create the makefile.

```
all: progOne.cpp progTwo.cpp

progOne: progOne.cpp fileInfo.cpp
    g++ progOne.cpp fileinfo.cpp -o progOne

progTwo: progTwo.cpp fileinfo.cpp
    g++ progTwo.cpp fileinfo.cpp -o progTwo.
```

I get the error: make: nothing to be done for 'all'.

Comment: `all: progOne progTwo` - note the absence of .cpp - that's not your "target", that's your source file.

Comment: why do you need one makefile for both programs? Is it one project? Just because the share two files isnt a good reason imho

Comment: As @MatsPetersson said, watch your targets and dependencies. If you have 10 minutes, read through [this](http://mrbook.org/blog/tutorials/make/)!

Comment: @Mats Petersson Thanks. seems to be working now.

Comment: Since your build process is this simple you can also rely entirely on builtin rules `all: progOne progTwo
progOne progTwo: fileInfo.o`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need:

```
all: progOne progTwo
```

This tells make that `all` depends on `progOne` and `progTwo`. If you use `all: progOne.cpp ...` then if `progOne.cpp` already exists, make will not need to do anything, and says "nothing to be done for all".

Of course, next you have to explain to make how `progOne` and `progTwo` depend on the source files, so that when you update the source-file, it rebuilds the executable file.

You may also want to add any header files for `progOne.cpp` to the dependencies, e.g. `progOne: progOne.cpp progOne.h` - so that if `progOne.h` is updated, the program is rebuilt.